# Ionic 5 Android signed image not showing

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic5

The signed version of android does not display images.
The application is in Ionic 5 and has this problem only in the android version while in iOS it works.

**UPDATE**

This is how I set the image tag:

```
<img class="featured-book-cover" [src]="book.url">
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to set src attribute with fix url

This **not** work:

```
<img class="featured-book-cover" src="https://copertine.hoepli.it/archivio/978/8836/9788836009138.jpg"/>
```

This work:

```
<img class="featured-book-cover" src="https://apps.edigeo.it/copertine/9788836009138.jpeg" />
```

Comment: Please, could you show some code? How is the `img` tags that handle the images, and how about the url? Unfortunately you didn't give us much information to help you, but just to suppose things.

Comment: I posted my code

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are sure that the **book** object exists at the time the App shows the page for the users and the url is under SSL certificate (https). Looking at your `img tag` it seems me you didn't close the tag. Please, try to do like this:

```
<img class="featured-book-cover" [src]="book.url" />
```

**UPDATES**

In my testes, both of your images works good. So please, could you see and share your meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; media-src *; connect-src *;">` declared in the `index.html` file, just to be sure there are no blocking images.

Are you using Cordova or Capacitor in your Ionic? In case of Cordova please, can you take a look into the `config.xml` file to see if the Cordova [allow list](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/allowlist/) is able to many domains:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

In case you are using Capacitor, please take a look into the `capacitor.config.ts` file and check if there are some proxy and do the set up as you need or just clean up it if necessary.

```
  server: {
    url: 'https://your-domain.com',        
    allowNavigation:[
      'your-domain.com',
      '*.your-domain.com/*',
      'localhost:8100/*'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I update my question with a fix url and with the img tag closed

Comment: The problem is only when you signed the app (android only). If you build without release optionI the images shown. I use Cordova and I already have the allow list in config.xml, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If I add "Content-Security-Policy" tag in index.html I have this error: Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *"

Comment: You can remove the `"default-src *"` from the Content Security Policy tag either improve it, as it was just a suggestion. It seems me your entire set up is correct. The last try I would suggest you is: remove the Android platform and add it again followed of the cordova prepare command: `ionic cordova platform rm android` next `ionic cordova platform add android` next `ionic cordova prepare android` and see if it solves the problems.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but nothing changes.
Could you tell me what changes between the build and the signed version?
Because this problem exists only on the signed version.
This problem exists only on Android on iOS everything works correctly.

If you sign the application, do you still see the images?

Comment: The main difference is that the signed version are a build process which pre-compiles templates and minifies JS so as to improve the performance of the application and it packages, shuffles, compressed and cryptograph the entire application.